# D-Bus: type-safe usage of signed 8-bit integers

Tags: c++, dbus, type-safety

According to the [D-Bus specification](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#basic-types), there are signed and unsigned types for 16-, 32- and 64-bit integers. However, for 8-bit integers, only an unsigned type ('y') is defined.

Background: I am thinking about a C++ variadic template, which shall map C++ classes to D-Bus type signatures  at *compile time* (e.g. `int64_t` <-> 'x', `std::string` <-> 's', `std::tuple<int64_t, std::string>` <-> '(xs)', `std::vector<std::tuple<int64_t, std::string>>` <-> 'a(xs)'.

Casting `int8_t` from/to `uint8_t` would not be type safe.

Is there any way to implement a type-safe transfer of signed bytes (`int8_t`) in D-Bus, which is still generic and I might have overseen?

Comment: Please [edit] the question title as well